# Como criar validação de usuários com níveis de acesso em codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, validação, orientação-a-objetos

tenho esse model e controle que verifica e valida os usuários cadastrados na tabela **tb_users** do banco de dados. Preciso de um script que verifica se o usuário é **0 ou 1** na coluna **nv_nivel**. Se o usuário for igual a **0** ele direciona para `redirect('usuario/home', 'refresh');` se for igual a **1** direciona para `redirect('admin/home', 'refresh');`

Segue abaixo o código **Model** e **Controller**.

**-> Model**

```
   class Login_model extends CI_Model {

    function ValidaLogin() {
        $this->db->where('hl_email', $this->input->post('email'));
        $this->db->where('pw_password', md5($this->input->post('senha')));
        $query = $this->db->get('tb_user');
        if ($query->num_rows == 1) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

**-> controller**

```
public function valida() {

        $this->load->model('login_model'); //Carrega o model
        $query = $this->login_model->ValidaLogin(); //Chama a função da Model que checa o usuário no BD

        if ($query) { //Se o Usuário e senha existir no mesmo registro...
            $data = array(
                'login' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'is_logged_in' => true
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            redirect('usuario/home', 'refresh');
        } else { // incorreto username ou password
            $info['msg'] = "Informações incorretas";
            $this->load->view('header_html');
            $this->load->view('header_view');
            $this->load->view('login/login_view', $info);
            $this->load->view('footer_view');
            $this->load->view('footer_html');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A primeira opção que tens é criar esse "sistema" de privilégio no braço. **Como?**

Na sua tabela de usuários ou em uma terceira relacionada, crie uma coluna chamada **role** ou **função** e determine um valor a tal.

Depois, quebrando com `if`, nós conseguimos distinguir o papel do usuário e determinar algo para ele. Por exemplo:

```php
if ($user->role == 1) {
    // é administrador
} else {
   // não é administrador
}
```

Ou, caso queira, você pode utilizar uma biblioteca pronta, como a [Ion Auth](https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth).

Infelizmente o CI não possui uma **role provider** nativa.

Comment: No caso preciso colocar essas informações no model e controller?

Comment: Então, primeiramente pensa que `role` é só mais uma coluna do banco de dados. Você precisa resgatar ela através do seu modelo e depois podes trabalhar com ela livremente nas views ou controllers. Em outras palavras, o model vai **resgatar** a função do usuário e a view ou o controller irão usufruir de tal recurso.

Answer (score 0):

O que você esta precisando é de um **ACL - ACESS CONTROL LIST**, existe um pronto que é muito bom chamado de **Ion Auth**.

Visite o site [Ion Auth Docs](http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/), e veja sua documentação, baixe e configure no seu projeto.

Comment: Não tinha visto, mais o @GuilhermeOderdenge também mencionou o Ion Auth.